# Preventing WritePrivateProfileString going to the registry

Tags: windows, winapi, ini

Is there any way to disable WritePrivateProfileString from writing to the registry and instead use the ini file that we provide to it? I see from the MSDN that you can disable file writes and exclusively use Registry, but not vice versa. I want to keep my program portable, at the same time, use standard win apis to store configuration data (instead of creating something new)..

Thanks

Comment: Surely unless you've explicitly set it to be redirected to the registry, it will go to disk?

Comment: I didnt explicitly set anything. For example, this is what I was doing to set up the ini file:  WritePrivateProfileString(L"Default",  L"MaxCmds", L"100", L"C:\\Temp\\Config.ini");

Comment: @Murlex Sorry for confusing you. I got my APIs mixed up.

Comment: @David. No problem. I appreciate pitching in with some insight nevertheless! Didn't know about the WriteProfileString before :)

Comment: @Murlex: It would make this question more useful if you stated whether you're using MFC as Stefan assumes, and if so added the MFC tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your ini file is getting mapped to the registry, then you've apparently added it to
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\IniFileMapping.  Delete that entry and your ini file will end up where you expect it.  Your line of code works as expected on my machine.

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725501%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: That was it. It was stuck in the registry at start, and so any subsequent write wasn't going through.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using MFC, since only that has its own versions of `WritePrivateProfileString` and similar functions. When you compile your code with newer Versions of MFC, you're automatically using the MFC equivalents of those APIs, and MFC simply uses the information you pass to the 'API's and writes/reads them from the registry.
To avoid this, don't write

> WritePrivateProfileString

in your code but

> ::WritePrivateProfileString

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Hook it (which you can do easily with a library such as [Microsoft Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/)).